# Merge each JavaScript object in huge array with another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of JavaScript object which has over millions of objects, I want to merge each object in the array with a specific object with fixed key and values

```
[{prop1:"a",prop2:"b"}, {prop1:"c",prop2:"d"}] -- Array of object


{id:"1","dept":"Finance"} -- object to be merge in
```

Currently I am iterating over each object in array and adding the key and value one by one which is very time consuming.

I am looking for an alternate solution in JavaScript to merge two object like a bulk merge without iterating on each object to save CPU time.

Comment: How do you expect to be able to alter every object in the array without iterating over each one? You can't get more efficient than O(n) and it sounds like you've already tried that solution.

Comment: Why not add these props while creating these objects.

Comment: You could *wrap* the array with another object, implementing the api you need, that only merges the given objects on access. Sort of a *lazy merge*. Though feasibility it depends on how that outer containing array is passed around / used.

Comment: @ElanHamburger, I have no idea if that is possible, as in past I have done object key conversion to string using regular expression without iterating over each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.assign()` to merge objects.

```
array_of_objects.forEach(obj => Object.assign(obj, object_to_merge_in));
```

Comment: will it be faster than iterating on each object and adding the key value pairs individually ?

Comment: I'd expect it to be, since it's highly optimized code in the JavaScript internals.

Comment: @RohanKumar I think a more realistic test is needed. http://jsben.ch/WZ2OV

Comment: @RohanKumar On your test my version is fastest by 5%. But the main difference is the reduced memory, which is not apparent with only 2 elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

At first for performance-wise, it is O(n) complexity. So there is no way out without doing a loop through each object whether you use `Object.assign`, `array.map` or any other method.

If you have so many json object manipulation related works in your project, life will be easier if you use [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

There are plenty of methods as your requirement in that library

```
    _.merge(object, [sources], [customizer], [thisArg])
    _.assign(object, [sources], [customizer], [thisArg])
    _.extend(object, [sources], [customizer], [thisArg])
    _.defaults(object, [sources])
    _.defaultsDeep(object, [sources])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) without using of loop to merge a new object in array of objects

```js
var objArr = [{prop1:"a",prop2:"b"}, {prop1:"c",prop2:"d"}],
    obj = {id:"1","dept":"Finance"} ;

var mapArr = objArr.map(x => Object.assign(x,obj));

console.log(mapArr);
```

Comment: Why create a new list with `map()`? `Object.assign()` modifies the object in place.

Comment: @Barmar Map is used to iterate an array internally, and Object.assign() is used to assign/copy an object from another. So we need to use map to iterate each object then copy a new Object to an existing one.

Comment: `Object.assign()` modifies the first argument in place, it doesn't create a new object.

Comment: You only get new objects if you write `Object.assign({}, x, obj)`

Comment: With over a million objects in the array, creating new copies might be a memory issue.

Comment: It might be a memory issue, but I have checked the performance for both code and found that the Object.assign(x, obj) is faster than that of your suggested one.  Please see the performance on http://jsben.ch/JTdwm and also checked on https://jsbench.me/

Comment: `Object.assign(x, obj)` is what I use in my answer, so I'm not sure what you mean by my suggested one. But I use `forEach` instead of `map` because there's no need to create a new array, since it merges the object in place.

Comment: I wasn't recommending `Object.assign({}, x, obj);`, just telling you that that would create new objects, your code doesn't.